# Добавление изображений к посту Meteor

Tags: загрузка, meteor

При создании блога на meteor js у меня появился вопрос, как лучше организовать добавления изображения к посту?

Для загрузки картинок на сервер я использовал пакет: "ostrio:files", который загружает файлы по пути ".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app/uploads/Images/". После загрузки изображения я получаю url картинки и загружаю её в базу данных с постами.

```
//добавление статьи
Template.addPost.events({
'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
        titlename: $(e.target).find('[name=titlename]').val(),
        posttext: $(e.target).find('[name=posttext]').val(),
        categore: $('#categores').val(),
//получение url картинки
        image: imagesURL
    };

    Meteor.call('postInsert',post,function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            throwError(error.reason);
        }
            Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
    });
},

'change #fileInput': function (e, template) {
    if (e.currentTarget.files && e.currentTarget.files[0]) {
        file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
        if (file) {
            var  uploadInstance = Images.insert({
                file: file,
                streams: 'dynamic',
                chunkSize: 'dynamic'
            }, false);
            uploadInstance.on('start', function() {
                template.currentUpload.set(this);
            });
            uploadInstance.on('end', function(error, fileObj) {
                if (error) {
                    alert('Загрузка не удалась: ' + error.reason);
                } else {

                    //сохранение ссылки
  imagesURL = '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app/uploads/Images/' + fileObj._id+ '.png';

                        console.log(imagesURL);
                        alert('Файл ' + fileObj.name + ' загружен!');
                        return imagesURL;
                }
                template.currentUpload.set(false);
            });

            uploadInstance.start();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Однако при использовании полученного url в качестве ссылки тега img не дает результатов. На экран выводится изображение битой картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вставки картинки

```
    <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{image}}">
```

Насколько я понимаю, то по умолчанию метеор ищет все медиа файлы в папке "public". С этим может быть связанна моя проблема. Использование относительных ссылок вроде:

".meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app/uploads/Images/" 
или 
"~/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/app/uploads/Images/"

результатов не дало.

Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой или использовал альтернативные способы добавления изображений к постам.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, картинки нужно брать по ссылке: [http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/Images/ИмяИзображения/original/ИмяИзображения](http://localhost:3000/cdn/storage/Images/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/original/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)